# Как написать android программу для управления люстрой через Webview?

Tags: android, java, webview

Добры вечер.

Я пытаюсь написать android программу для управления люстрой через Webview. Собрал вот эту схему http://habrahabr.ru/post/159745/ (если кому интересно могу дать полезные советы по сборке этого девайса) роутер настроил, wifi сеть назвал ON-OFF адрес роутера 192.168.1.1 и из видео урока https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrROaEpcIp4 сделал простои браузер. Всё работает, но есть некоторые пожелания.

Я хочу сделать так чтоб при включении приложения он подключался именно к wifi сети ON-OFF и потом открывал адрес роутера 192.168.1.1. Если он не в зоне действия или не возможно открыть адрес роутера 192.168.1.1 выводил соответственное сообщения.
Пожалуйста если можно объясните подробно как это сделать.
С уважением Том

Comment: @tombender, какая у вас защита WiFi (WPA2/WEP/WPA)? Скрыт ли SSID сети? Дополните вопрос и я вам помогу.

P.S. Если бы у меня была такая люстра, то я делал бы всё через свой радиоканал или через Bluetooth. Вдруг у меня будет незащищённая сеть и какой-нибудь сосед решит поиздеваться над моим светом?)

Comment: а почему нельзя люстру подключить к основной wifi, пусть у нее будет свой айпи. Все проблемы сразу решаются.

А люстра - wifi точка...

Comment: Добры вечер SuperCreeper
Очень рад что Вы помогайте.
защита у WiFi WPA2.
нет SSID сети не скрыт

Добры вечер KoVadim
Я тоже подумал подключить к основному роутеру, но, во-первых, что это меняет всё равно программа должна подключатся к домашнему роутеру и открыт IP MR-3020. Во вторых домашний роутер я отключаю когда ухожу на работу а  MR-3020 будет всё время включён и я пока открою дверь буду включат свет чтоб не споткнутся в темноте. Но я понимаю есть у такой схемы и плюсы можно било бы включить свет с помощи интернета но зачем мне с работы включат свет дома?

Comment: Добры вечер KoVadim
Я тоже подумал подключить к основному роутеру, но, во-первых, что это меняет всё равно программа должна подключатся к домашнему роутеру и открыт IP MR-3020. Во вторых домашний роутер я отключаю когда ухожу на работу а  MR-3020 будет всё время включён и я пока открою дверь буду включат свет чтоб не споткнутся в темноте. Но я понимаю есть у такой схемы и плюсы можно било бы включить свет с помощи интернета но зачем мне с работы включат свет дома?

Comment: > Но я понимаю есть у такой схемы и плюсы можно било бы включить свет с помощи интернета но зачем мне с работы включат свет дома?

да все очень просто. Вот поедите в отпуск. А дома будете включать-выключать свет. Соседи и воры будут считать, что Вы дома.

Вариант два. Пойдете к подруге/любовнице/друзьям-рыбакам в гости, но об этом не нужно, что бы знали другие. Они стоят возле Вашего дома и спрашивают, дома ли Вы. А Вы легко можете светом помигать.

А выключать wifi, пока на работе...  Я свой роутер за последние пару лет если раза два и выключал, и то, только потому, что он зависал.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте это. Проверил на WiFi WPA2-PSK

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wifiConf = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConf.SSID = "\"ON-OFF\"";
    wifiConf.wepKeys[0] = "\"(пароль)\"";
    wifiConf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    wifiConf.preSharedKey = "\"(пароль)\"";
    wifiConf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
    wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

    wifiConf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wifiConf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wifiConf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wifiConf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wifiConf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

    wifi.addNetwork(wifiConf);
    wifi.saveConfiguration();
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        Log.e("SSID", i.SSID);
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + "ON-OFF" + "\"")) {

            Log.e("RSSI_VALUE", "NET_ID " + String.valueOf(i.networkId));

            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            boolean enable = wifi.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            Log.e("RSSI_VALUE", "ENABLE_WIFI " + String.valueOf(enable));

            break;
        }           
     }
```

В Manifest добавить

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Для подключение требуется время, поэтому прежде чем загружать страницу стоит удостовериться что подключение завершено.

Comment: Добры день Kaminsky. 
Может у Вас найдётся время чтоб посмотреть проект который написал SuperCreeper. Там есть некоторые ошибки (они описаны на форуме) и я не знаю, как их исправить.
Пожалуйста помогите.
С уважением Том.

Answer (score 3):

Эх, опоздал немного.

Написал приложение, выполняющую поставленную задачу. Обязательно измените данные в классе Constants, я использовал свои для теста. А всё остальное подгоните сами по надобности.

[Исходники (APK находится в папке /bin)](http://fs1.d-h.st/download/00133/659/LampOverWiFi.zip)

Comment: Добры день SuperCreeper.
Я очень благодарен что Вы мне помогайте сейчас верю что ещё остались хорошие люди на этом свете. Хорошо что Вы дали готовы проект ото я не смог разобраться в коде который написал Kaminsky Куда и как его вставлять а проект импортировал и всё. Дело в том что я не программист а в электронике разбираюсь если буду полезен огромным удовольствием помогу.

Comment: SuperCreeper   Я  поверил программу очень круто но оказалось что если в телефоне отключён WiFi он не включает его а просто пишет что питается подключится к ON-OFF и показывает бели экран вот так он делает и тогда когда он не в радиусе действия то ест он не выводить сообщения что сет не доступно или не в зоне. При запуске с включённым WiFi он подключается к ON-OFF но повторном включений программы он отключается и снова подключается к ON-OFF. Когда он пере подключается происходит ошибка открытия адреса http:// 192.168.1.1 и браузер выводить ошибку что страница по этому адресу не доступно.

Comment: Если можно сделайте так чтоб он не пере подключался когда телефон уже подключен к WiFi ON-OFF и если можно убрать ошибку загрузки страницы веб браузера или хотя бы убрать адрес роутера.
С уважением Том

Comment: @tombender, к сожалению, у меня уже больше нет времени разбираться в коде, мне надо делать другие проекты. Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь найдёт время изменить мой код, чтобы помочь вам.

Comment: @tombender, так обратились бы ко мне, если не понятно) Код возможно пригодиться другим пользователям.
 А я готов посмотреть проект SuperCreeper, что бы помочь Вам. Можете оставить контакты, что бы не флудить и я Вам напишу.

Comment: Я очень благодарен!!!
tom.bender@mail.ru